# Variable sometimes not saving data nextjs 13 api - TS

Tags: typescript, server, child-process, next.js13

In short:
Sometimes at first time, it seems to reset the 'child'.

I am working on a project where i want to start a local server inside a local server, to do this I am using an API.
However the problem that I run into is that it does not save the 'child' let at the start, so if I start the first server and request a post with the command 'start' then wait and request a get, the returned result would be null, then I could request post with 'start' again and it do as usual (gives an can't open on this port error) but the second time it does save the child (just not the first time).

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { ChildProcess, spawn } from "child_process";
let child: ChildProcess | undefined;

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  if (child) {
    console.log(child.pid);
  } else {
    console.log(null);
  }
  const command = await request.json();

  if (command == "start") {
    if (!child) {
      child = spawn("node", ["minecraft-server/start-server/app.js"], {
        stdio: ["inherit", "inherit", "inherit", "ipc"],
      }); //run "node minecraft-server\start-server\app.js"

      // send a custom command to the child process
      child.send({ command: "START" });
      console.log("new id: ", child.pid);

      return NextResponse.json({ message: "started server" }, { status: 200 });
    } else {
      return NextResponse.json(
        { message: "server already started" },
        { status: 400 }
      );
    }
  } else if (command == "stop") {
    console.log("called stop");
    if (child) {
      console.log("stopping");

      // send another custom command to the child process
      child.send({ command: "STOP" });

      // child.kill();
      child = undefined; // clear the child variable

      return NextResponse.json({ message: "stopped server" }, { status: 200 });
    } else {
      return NextResponse.json(
        { message: "no server to stop" },
        { status: 400 }
      );
    }
  }

  return NextResponse.json({ message: "wrong command" }, { status: 400 });
}

export async function GET(request: Request) {
  if (child) {
    return NextResponse.json({ message: child.pid }, { status: 200 });
  } else {
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "null" }, { status: 200 });

  }
}
```

Can anyone help with fixing it?